# Progress visualization in parallelized sections

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I built a data analysis software where I tried to keep the functions short and without side effects if possible. Then I used OpenMP to parallelize `for`-loops where possible. This works well, except that progress is not visible.

Then I introduced statements like `if (i % 10 == 0) print_status(i);` to give a status message in the loop. Since all operations are going to take about the same time I did not change the OpenMP scheduling policy which just divides the loop range into a number of chunks and assigns each chunk to a thread. The output will then be something around

```
0
100
200
10
110
210
…
```

which is not really helpful to the user. I could change the scheduling policy such that the elements are roughly processed in order, but that would come with a synchronization cost that is not needed by the actual work to be done. It might even make it harder for the prefetcher since the loop indexes for each threads are not contiguous any more.

This issue is even worse since I have an expensive function which will takes minutes to complete. I run three of them in parallel. So I have

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    result[i] = expensive(i);
}
```

Currently the function `expensive` will just print something like “Working on `i = 0` and I am at 56 %”. This output the interleaves (linewise, I used `omp critical` with `std::cout`) with the other three running instances. Judging the overall progress of the system is not that easy and a bit cumbersome.

I think I could solve this by passing a functor to the `expensive` function which can then be called with the current state. The functor would know about the number of `expensive` instances and could compute the global progress. A progress bar would need to have multiple active parts depending on the scheduling policy, just like a BitTorrent download. But just having the ratio of the done to the total work would be a great feature.

This will complicate the interfaces of all the long-running functions and I am not sure whether this is really worth the complication it brings with it.

It is probably impossible to get status information out of a function without introducing side effects. I just do not want to make the code hard to maintain just for unified progress information.

Is there any sensible way to do this without adding a lot more complication to the system?

Comment: If you can judge a priori which of the three calls to expensive will most likely need the longest time (perhaps the one with the largest input?), you could simply only print progress from that call and silence the others, as the total parallel time will be the max of all threads.
Or what about using a shared variable to count the total progress?

Comment: Estimating the max is a nice idea! The problem is that the functions which are run in parallel do not even know that. Using a shared variable would mean that I introduce side effects to them. Printing output in only one function would mean the addition of another parameter, although that can have a default. This is not an unmaintanable change

Comment: If you always execute expensive() in a parallel block you might be able to circumvent the additional parameter by running your largest work in the zero-th index, then using schedule(static) and omp_get_thread_num to only print progress for thrednum 0. Maybe there is a construct for checking whether you even are in a parallel section as well in your expensive() function. If you have more work elements that threads it gets more complicated.